# Replace a word that comes after a number

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace 'Foo' with '\nFoo' (adding a break line before) in this

```
123123Foo 12312FooTest
```

I tried to use the following expression in python

```
[0-9]\KFoo
```

but I get this error

```
re.error: bad escape \K at position 7
```

Comment: What did you intend with `\K`? That's not a valid character class.

Comment: Where's the K come from?

Comment: Python `re` does not support `\K` You can use 2 capture groups `([0-9])(Foo)` and replace with `\1\n\2`

Comment: Or use a lookbehind and lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` with look-behind ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Vg0Nmb/1)):

```py
import re

s = "123123Foo 12312FooTest"

s = re.sub(r"(?<=\d)Foo", "\nFoo", s)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
123123
Foo 12312
FooTest
```